# Invalid literal error when finding sum of number

Tags: python, string, int

I have a txt file:

`10 5`

I'm trying to find the sum of those numbers:

`sum([int(s.strip()) for s in open('file.txt').readlines()]).`

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 5'
```

Comment: Your line is indeed a string: "10 5". You have to split the string using `s.split()` for instance.

Comment: your question is not clear ! is your `txt` file contain whitespace or empty line ?

Comment: It contains whitespace.@Kasra

Comment: so how many ? you must clarify your question ! for get a proper answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strip doesn't separate the numbers. You are trying to convert the string "10 5" into an integer. `int(str)` can only convert numbers without any other ASCII symbols. You have to use `split` to split up the string.

```
sum = 0
with open('file.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        for num in line.split(' '):
            sum += int(num)
```

It would be easier using numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('file.txt').sum()
```